# python opencv - get box coordinates of central object by color

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I would need a way to detect the size and position of the color blob representing the central object in a photo.

i have prepared a image that should explain what i am after. this is done in photoshop, so its just a handmade explanation. I need to simplify the object, in oder to remove reflections and small details. Then I need to find the outer box coordinates to be able to locate it in the image.

The object can have any color, and will always differentiate from the background. I am interested in the object that covers the central pixel of the image.

How can this be done in python using opencv?

thank you

Original image:
[image]

simplyfied color-blob image
[image]

needed box:
[image]

Comment: Use kmeans to reduce colors. Then find the color in the middle of the picture. Then threshold on that color. Then get the largest contour. Then get the bounding box of the contour

Comment: @fmw42 thank you, tried but its veeeerry slow. takes about 5 seconds on a i7 cpu on a 2,4 mpx image. is there something quicker?

Comment: Reduce the number of attempts or change the termination criteria

Comment: You can use just a few attempts. You do not need accurate colors, just reduced number of colors. Set the number of colors to some small number 3-6 for example and just a few attempts. Experiment and find the the number of colors and fewest number of attempts that looks reasonable to isolate your color object.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried that, and managed to get down to about 800 ms, that takes still too long. but it worked quickly with this: `hls_array = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS )
                    h = hls_array[:, :, 0]
                    img2 = h & int("11000000", 2)` now on to the box extraction part...